# Can a method parameter take more than one @StringDef?

Tags: android, annotations

I have 2 @StringDef s that map to a color and a player as follows:

```
//Define the first @StringDef interface

@StringDef({X_COLOR , O_COLOR})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ColorPreference{}

public static final String X_COLOR = "x_color";
public static final String O_COLOR = "O_color";

//Define the second @StringDef interface

@StringDef({PLAYER_X , PLAYER_Y})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface PlayerPreferences{};

public static final String PLAYER_X = "player_x";
public static final String PLAYER_Y = "player_y";
```

And I want to implement a method that saves to my sharedPreferences that takes either a @ColorPreference or @PlayerPreference like this:

```
public static void saveInPreferences(@ColorPreference || @PlayerPreference String value){}
```

Is this possible in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. If you must differentiate between String types, create 2 APIs, "saveColor" and "savePlayer".